# Overriding default parameters in C#

Tags: c#, default-parameters

Really simple to replicate, the output is bizarre;

Expected output is "bbb bbb"
Actual output is "aaa bbb"

Has anyone got any MSDN explanation of this behaviour? I couldn't find any.

```
((a)new b()).test();
new b().test();


public class a
{
    public virtual void test(string bob = "aaa ")
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class b : a
{
    public override void test(string bob = "bbb ")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(bob);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does ((a)(new b())).test() give the results you want?

Comment: Expected output according to *who*?

Comment: I believe that it is invalid to change the default value of an optional parameter while overriding a method.  Doesn't that change the method signature ?

Comment: Only if you dont understand the `virtual` and `override` keywords!

Comment: @Frederik: Shouldn't this throw a compiler warning if it is invalid?

Comment: @user1567896 and if it was invalid, I suspect it would

Comment: Indeed, the compiler should complain when it is invalid.  It doesn't, but Resharper does ...

Comment: @Frederik It's not *invalid*, it's just potentially *unwise*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you expect "bbb bbb"?

Since you are casting the instance to `a`, the only information to the compiler on the first call is the version with `"aaa"`, so *that value is what is used*.

In the second version without the cast, the compiler can see the `"bbb"`, so *that value is what is used*.

Polymorphism impacts which method is *invoked* - but it doesn't impact the parameters passed. Essentially, the default values are supplied **by the compiler** (at the call-site), so your code is actually equivalent to:

```
((a)new b()).test("aaa");
new b().test("bbb");
```

where the `"aaa"` and `"bbb"` is supplied **at compile time**, by inspection of the resolved method.

Comment: So, to re-emphasize, default values are implemented at compile time, not runtime?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu yes; I already added in a bit more to highlight that